# pandas replace column values by another dataframe and apply calculation to it

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. I'd like to replace imp values from df1 with conditions imp = 0 and format = opening, with the same media and imp values in df2, and then apply calculation with imp*day in the same column

df1

| media | imp | format | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | opening | 2 |
| B | 0 | feeds | 1 |
| C | 120 | opening | 3 |

df2

| media | imp |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 150 |

my ideal output would be

| media | imp | format | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 200 | opening | 2 |
| B | 0 | feeds | 1 |
| C | 120 | opening | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mask and conditionally update the merged `imp` column

```py
m = df1['imp'].eq(0) & df1['format'].eq('opening')

df1['imp'] = df1['imp'].mask(m, df1['day'] * df1.merge(df2, on='media', how='left')['imp_y'])
```

```
print(df1)

  media  imp   format  day
0     A  200  opening    2
1     B    0    feeds    1
2     C  120  opening    3
```